# Date format is not working in kibana's date histogram

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to populate the area chart with my date fields.
It is not working in kibana, when I check with elasticsearch query it's working there.

[image]

It's working in ElasticSearch query.

[image]

My mapping is below:

```
PUT test1
{
"settings": {
"index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true
},
"mappings": {
"each_file": {
"properties": {
"Size": {"type": "integer","ignore_malformed": false },
"Path ID": {"type": "integer","ignore_malformed": false },
"Family Item Number": {"type": "integer","ignore_malformed": false },
"Creation Time": {"type": "date", "format": "E dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"},
"Document Creation Time": {"type": "date", "format": "E dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"},
"Document Modification Time": {"type": "date", "format": "E dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"},
"Email Received Time": {"type": "date", "format": "E dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"},
"Email Sent Time": {"type": "date", "format": "E dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"},
"Modification Time": {"type": "date", "format": "E dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"}
}
}
}
}
```

My date format : Document Creation Time : Fri 02 Nov 2001 06:28:37 AM IST

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `Document Modification Time` field is malformed as it appears under `_ignored` in your search query response. You have the ignore malformed field setting set to true in your index mapping.

Comment: I set ignore malformed true , still it's not working.

Comment: The malformed field is not indexed as per Elastic docs so it appears that field does not exist in your index documents hence you see nothing when populating it in a visualization in Kibana.

Comment: So what should I do now to index documents in kibana , should I change my mapping?

Comment: How are you indexing data into Elasticsearch ? Try to fix the issue at source to prevent malformed fields.